# How to install a plugin from a iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, plugins

Can someoneone help me making a plugin work from an iframe? I need the plugin to work on the parent window. this is the plugin code:

```
<script id="oada_ma_toolbar_script">
var oada_ma_license_key="9R7cmcUy6fNWYuPJ85Fc7l5ucC0Mf1z64ldYDTQuEpGcWmTj4h";
var oada_ma_license_url="https://api.maxaccess.io/scripts/toolbar/9R7cmcUy6fNWYuPJ85Fc7l5ucC0Mf1z64ldYDTQuEpGcWmTj4h";
(function(s,o,g){
a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.src=g;
a.setAttribute("async","");
a.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
a.setAttribute("crossorigin","anonymous");
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(document,"script",oada_ma_license_url+oada_ma_license_key);
</script>
```

Unfortunately I used a template from godaddy site builder and my options are very very limited. They allow me to insert custom html/css but they force it to be into an iframe! please help

thanks in advance

Comment: What are the values of s, o and g passed to the function?

Comment: I am sorry I am not an expert and I don't know what that means